# Change input text based on select inside Modal

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I know that there are already some posts about the same issue but in my case it seems that I'm unable to solve the problem since my content is inside a modal.

This modal contains a form, a select and a submit button, the issue I think arises on how the body of the modal is implemented since it appends X number of selects and buttons depending of the items found.

Below the code of the modal:

```
<form action="/foo/update_foo" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div id="flash-overlay-modal" class="modal fade {{ $modalClass or '' }}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">{{ $title }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>{!! $body !!}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Save changes">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Ignore</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the code that gets appended to the $body of the modal:

```
<div id="modal" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="lead">
            <span style="color:red">{{ $deleted->foo }}</span>
            with quantity {{  $item['quantity'] }} has been removed, please select a replacement.
        </p>
        <div>
            <select class="selectpicker" name="foo" id="foo">
                @foreach($replacements as $replacement):
                <option value="{{ $replacement->id }}">{{ $replacement->FOO}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="{{$item['quantity'] }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="fooBar" value="{{ $fooBar }}">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Description:</span>
            <input id="description" type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="" />
        </div>
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I add the JavaScript to the modal, it doesn't work as it takes it from the parent page.

Any idea of what could it be done.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this with angular js

here is a example

```js
angular.module('pdl', []).controller('player', function($scope) {
  $scope.players = [{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Nadal",
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Federer"
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="pdl" ng-controller="player">
  <input type="text" ng-model="player.name" />
  <select ng-model="player" ng-options="player as player.name for player in players">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer but  I am not used to angular. 
I've a question, so  by looking at the code, how would I adapt the angular module to my code as in this case my select receives its input from the controller?